# Can you use the value of a variable to select an already defined variable with that same name?

Tags: java

I'm trying to try something out for my AP statistics class where I need to randomly select five words from the lyrics of a song and calculate the average length of those strings. This is what I have so far: (There's 297 lyrics but I don't want to type all of those out if it won't work)

```
        String n001 = "I";
        String n002 = "look";
        String n003 = "and";
        String n004 = "stare";
        String n005 = "so";
        
        Random bob = new Random();
     
        String num_1 = String.format("%03d", bob.nextInt(298)); 
        System.out.println(num_1);
        String num_2 = String.format("%03d", bob.nextInt(298)); 
        System.out.println(num_2);
        String num_3 = String.format("%03d", bob.nextInt(298)); 
        System.out.println(num_3);
        String num_4 = String.format("%03d", bob.nextInt(298)); 
        System.out.println(num_4);
        String num_5 = String.format("%03d", bob.nextInt(298)); 
        System.out.println(num_5);
        
        String num1 = "n" + num_1;
```

What I can't figure out is how to take the value in num1 to select one of the Strings named the same thing. I need to do that for all five selected random numbers.

I'm sure there's a way to do this, but it's my first year in a CS class and I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

Comment: Java and Javascript are two very different programming languages

Comment: And you should first learn about arrays (and possibly hashmaps), without those you will have a very hard time to write the code for things like these

Comment: If you have variables like `n001`, `n002`, etc, then you should probably be using an array instead.

Comment: You want either an array or a map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a suggestion.

- put all the words in a List<String>
  (e.g. `List<String> = new ArrayList<>()`)
- Use `Collections.shuffle` to shuffle the list.
- then take the first 5 entries.

Doing the above will guarantee you won't repeat any word unless there are duplicates in the list.

Figuring out how to average the lengths is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
package RandomLyric;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class RandomLyric 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        List<String>bob = new ArrayList<>();
        
        bob.add("I");
        bob.add("look");
        bob.add("and");
        bob.add("stare");
        bob.add("so");
        bob.add("deep");
        bob.add("in");
        bob.add("your");
        bob.add("eyes");
        bob.add("I");
        bob.add("touch");
        bob.add("on");
        bob.add("you");
        bob.add("more");
        bob.add("and");
        bob.add("more");
        bob.add("every");
        bob.add("time");
        bob.add("when");
        bob.add("you");
        bob.add("leave");
        bob.add("I'm");
        bob.add("begging");
        bob.add("you");
        bob.add("not");
        bob.add("to");
        bob.add("go");
        bob.add("call");
        bob.add("your");
        bob.add("two");
        bob.add("or");
        bob.add("three");
        bob.add("times");
        bob.add("in");
        bob.add("a");
        bob.add("row");
        bob.add("Such");
        bob.add("a");
        bob.add("funny");
        bob.add("thing");
        bob.add("for");
        bob.add("me");
        bob.add("to");
        bob.add("try");
        bob.add("to");
        bob.add("explain");
        bob.add("how");
        bob.add("I'm");
        bob.add("feeling");
        
        
        Collections.shuffle(bob);
        java.util.Iterator<String> itr=bob.iterator();
        String num1_ = itr.next();
        double num1 = num1_.length();
        System.out.printf( num1_ + ": %.0f",+ num1);
        System.out.println("");
        
        String num2_ = itr.next();
        double num2 = num2_.length();
        System.out.printf( num2_ + ": %.0f",+ num2);
        System.out.println("");
        
        String num3_ = itr.next();
        double num3 = num1_.length();
        System.out.printf( num3_ + ": %.0f",+ num3);
        System.out.println("");
        
        String num4_ = itr.next();
        double num4 = num4_.length();
        System.out.printf( num4_ + ": %.0f",+ num4);
        System.out.println("");
        
        String num5_ = itr.next();
        double num5 = num5_.length();
        System.out.printf( num5_ + ": %.0f",+ num5);
        System.out.println("");
        
        double avg = (num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5)/5;
        System.out.println("The length of the five randomly selected strings is: " + avg);
        
        
        
        
        
        
    }

}
```

Thank you!!!! I got it all together now!